# AJAX pagination in my Django project pointing to 'page not found'

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

My django app has a favorite section with a favorite list for the user to save favorite products in it. For now the user can navigate through the favorite list using regular Django pagination set on 5 items per page.
But I want a smoother user experience and I want to use AJAX to display the content.

views.py:

```
def pagination(request):    
    model = SavedProduct.objects.all()    
    number_of_item = 5   
    paginatorr = Paginator(model,number_of_item)    
    first_page = paginatorr.page(1).object_list    
    page_range = paginatorr.page_range
    context = {
    'paginatorr':paginatorr,
    'first_page':first_page,
    'page_range':page_range
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        page_n = request.POST.get('page_n', None) 

        serializer = pagination_ser(paginatorr.page(page_n).object_list, many=True) 
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'register/ajax.html',context)
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'register'
urlpatterns = [
    path('pagination/', views.pagination, name='pagination'),    
    ]
```

ajax.html:

```
<body> 
    <div id="register_list">
        {% for i in first_page %}
        <h2>{{i.sub_product.real_name}}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for i in page_range %}
    <button class='fav_nav' href="{{i}}">{{i}}</button>
    {% endfor %}
```

script.js:

```
$('.fav_nav').on('click',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();     
  var page_n = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(page_n)
  var url = '/register/pagination/'; 
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url, 
              data : {    
              page_n : page_n, 
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
          },
          success: function (resp) {                
              $('#register_list').html('')
             $.each(resp, function(i, val) {                 
              $('#register_list').append('<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>')
             });
          },
          error: function () {}
      }); 
});
```

But `event.preventDefault()` is not working, whenever I click on a pagination ling I get a **Page Not Found** error.

Comment: Try changing it to class=“fav_nav” instead of id

Comment: I've made the change. Now I get a `blocked by CORS policy` error.

Comment: Can you add the console error?

Comment: Maybe it's because I turned `a` into `button` (question edited)

Comment: Change $(‘#fav_nav’) to $(‘.fav_nav’)

Comment: I already id,  I just forgot to update the question.

Comment: Changing it to a button wouldn’t raise this error the CORS error tends to be raised by posting to another domain, if you can provide the error from the console I may be able to help further

Comment: I had the CORS error because I tried to redirect my AJAX call to another URL. No I am using the url from the question and I get this error in my console: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/pagination/%7B%%20url%20'register:pagination'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Is your JavaScript in your html template or is it in a js file?

Comment: I moved it to a .js file

Comment: Your Django syntax doesn’t get loaded in js files move it back to the html template